# use rss from different website to automatically publish their post in your website?

Tags: rss, publish

Is there is any way that you can use a rss from a website and automatically publish their post in your website? Or anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/

This service makes it really easy to do what you are asking.